# Which GTK for 18.04

Tags: 18.04, themes, gtk

I am trying to edit a theme to customize it to my liking. Mostly change colours. It has the following folders

[image]

GTK folders have `gtk.css` and `gtk-dark.css`. Which `gtk.css` should I edit for change to work with 18.04 ? What is the GTK related to 18.04 ? Is there any other file I would need to edit ? The theme is " Materia "

https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme

Thanks

Update 1:

Not able to locate the CSS class to change the border-bottom colour

[image: change header border-bottom]

Update 2:

gtk.css in gtk 3.22 in plain Materia- Google Drive

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ntA-mDEjFdyeT93Y62Lm9n-yPDi9qtLw/view?usp=sharing

Update 3 :

Looks like I got the code right, but border-bottom is still white :(

```
:not(headerbar) .caja-pathbar button, .caja-pathbar :not(headerbar) button, :not(headerbar)
.path-bar button {
  border-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center calc(100% - 1px), #03a9f4 0%, transparent 0%) 0 0 0/0 0 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

:not(headerbar) .caja-pathbar button:checked, .caja-pathbar :not(headerbar) button:checked, :not(headerbar)
.path-bar button:checked {
  border-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center calc(100% - 1px), #03a9f4 100%, transparent 0%) 0 0 2/0 0 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make the required changes with the folder you have provided https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NgWdbxKmIbh38WJo9vFDI4wYEfXu1UTz/view?usp=sharing

navigate to `.../gtk-3.22/gtk.css` edit the file to add the below content at around line number 632

```
.path-bar.linked:not(.vertical) > button:checked {
  border-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center calc(100% - 1px), #FF0000 100%, transparent 0%) 0 0 2/0 0 2px;
}
```

Change the color `#FF0000` to your liking.

[image]

---

If you are not following Manual Installation Procedure:

then open the file `gtk.css` for the `Materia` Theme and add the below content at line number around 631

```
.path-bar.linked:not(.vertical) > button:checked {
  border-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center calc(100% - 1px), #1A73E8 100%, transparent 0%) 0 0 2/0 0 2px;
}
```

[image]

---

https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme#manual-installation

```
Manual Installation

Run the following commands in the terminal:

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme
cd materia-theme
sudo ./install.sh
```

for `Materia` theme:

open the `gtk.css` file and look for below content at line number around 1566 Col 83

```
.caja-pathbar button:checked,
.path-bar.linked:not(.vertical) > button:checked {
  border-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center calc(100% - 1px), #1A73E8 100%, transparent 0%) 0 0 2/0 0 2px;
}
```

Change the color #1A73E8 to your liking.

[image]

---

for example: If you take `materia-compact` theme, look for the below content in the `gtk.css` file.

```
.caja-pathbar button:checked,
.path-bar.linked:not(.vertical) > button:checked {
  border-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center calc(100% - 1px), #00FF00 100%, transparent 0%) 0 0 2/0 0 2px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you good at this ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189474/unable-to-build-yaru-cursor-theme-from-github