# Unable to build Yaru Cursor theme from Github

Tags: 18.04, github, cursor-theme

I was trying to change the " busy " and " watch " art for Yaru cursor. As instructed in the `readme` file, I installed `python-pil` and `x11-apps` and successfully rendered the cursor theme. I now have the `bitmaps` folder. But when I try `./x11-make.sh`, I get

```
$ ./x11-make.sh
Error reading config file!
Error reading config file!
```

What is wrong ? How can I fix this and complete the build ? Thanks

Ref : https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/tree/master/icons/src/cursors

Answer (score 0):

I was trying different combinations and finally was able to build the cursor theme. In the `bitmaps` folder at path shown below, delete the folder and icons in it. Keep the .in files intact.

> https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/tree/master/icons/src/cursors/bitmaps

Then use this command within the `cursors` folder in Terminal

```
./render-cursors.py source-cursors.svg
```

Once that is over, try `./x11-make.sh` command in the same Terminal window

Give it a bit of time and there will be a folder called `Suru`next to the `src` folder

This has worked fine for me so far. If you are confused try this Readme file

https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/master/icons/src/cursors/README.md

Good luck.